# creating a group of rows and selecting the last group from the rows

Tags: r

Creating a group of rows and selecting the last group from the rows.

Below we have a 25 rows in total - I want to create a 5 groups- where each group will have 5 rows, after the grouping is done, I want to select only the last group.

I don't want  to do using slicing or indexing as it will static, it should select the last group automatically.

```
A           B           C 

0           0           0
0           0           0
0           0           0
0           0           0
0.000342936 0           0
0.002743484 0           0.000355999
0.009259259 0           0.002847989
0.021947874 0.000342936 0.009611962
0.042866941 0.002743484 0.022783909
0.074074074 0.009259259 0.044499822
0.117626886 0.021947874 0.076895692
0.17558299  0.042866941 0.122107512
0.25        0.074074074 0.182271271
0.342935528 0.117626886 0.259522962
0.456447188 0.17558299  0.355998576
0.592592593 0.25        0.473834105
0.753429355 0.342935528 0.615165539
0.941015089 0.456447188 0.782128871
1.157407407 0.592592593 0.976860093
1.404189089 0.752980901 1.201011401
1.681043579 0.937427456 1.454299824
1.987179487 1.145299145 1.735958595
2.321805424 1.375962857 2.045220947
2.684129999 1.628785481 2.381320116
3.073361823 1.903133903 2.743489334
```

Expected output:

Last five rows from the above 25 rows.

```
     A           B           C
1.681043579 0.937427456 1.454299824
1.987179487 1.145299145 1.735958595
2.321805424 1.375962857 2.045220947
2.684129999 1.628785481 2.381320116
3.073361823 1.903133903 2.743489334
```

Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `tail`

```
no_of_groups <- 5
tail(df, nrow(df)/no_of_groups)

#          A         B        C
#21 1.681044 0.9374275 1.454300
#22 1.987179 1.1452991 1.735959
#23 2.321805 1.3759629 2.045221
#24 2.684130 1.6287855 2.381320
#25 3.073362 1.9031339 2.743489
```

---

We could wrap it in `floor` in case when number of rows are not completely divisible by `no_of_groups`

```
#Removing one row
df <- df[-1, ]

tail(df, floor(nrow(df)/no_of_groups))

#      A        B        C
#1.987179 1.145299 1.735959
#2.321805 1.375963 2.045221
#2.684130 1.628785 2.381320
#3.073362 1.903134 2.743489
```

This would now return only last 4 rows which are in the last group.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one?

```
 q=read_table("                  A           B           C 
              0           0           0
              0           0           0
              0           0           0
              0           0           0
              0.000342936 0           0
              0.002743484 0           0.000355999
              0.009259259 0           0.002847989
              0.021947874 0.000342936 0.009611962
              0.042866941 0.002743484 0.022783909
              0.074074074 0.009259259 0.044499822
              0.117626886 0.021947874 0.076895692
              0.17558299  0.042866941 0.122107512
              0.25        0.074074074 0.182271271
              0.342935528 0.117626886 0.259522962
              0.456447188 0.17558299  0.355998576
              0.592592593 0.25        0.473834105
              0.753429355 0.342935528 0.615165539
              0.941015089 0.456447188 0.782128871
              1.157407407 0.592592593 0.976860093
              1.404189089 0.752980901 1.201011401
              1.681043579 0.937427456 1.454299824
              1.987179487 1.145299145 1.735958595
              2.321805424 1.375962857 2.045220947
              2.684129999 1.628785481 2.381320116
              3.073361823 1.903133903 2.743489334")


 q%>%
   mutate(num=ceiling(row_number()/5))%>%
   filter(num==max(num))%>%
   select(-num)
# A tibble: 5 x 3
      A     B     C
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  1.68 0.937  1.45
2  1.99 1.15   1.74
3  2.32 1.38   2.05
4  2.68 1.63   2.38
5  3.07 1.90   2.74
```